# Master and PhD Track Program in Russia for a Couple

Tags: phd, two-body-problem, russia

I'm in a dilemma. I'm an international student. My wife and I are accepted and will attend to a master's program in mathematics. The university is located in Moscow, Russia. The university has subject ranking among top 100.

Today, we have been informed of an option to study in a track program (2 years masters + 4 years PhD) which comes with an increased financial support. We were planning to apply for other high ranking PhD programs around the world. The difficulty is that we don't know if we can manage to get in the same PhD Mathematics program (or within the same city) after our master's. And we don't know if we will be able to adapt to Moscow or the university.

One thing we know for sure is that for now we both wish to study mathematics further.

What is your advice?

Should we commit for 6 years or struggle to find a different PhD program?

What can you say about doing graduate mathematics studies in Moscow?

Comment: The intent of SE is to answer questions whose answers also will be useful for people who are not the original poser of the question.  We do not give personal advice.

Comment: You can probably leave early. I doubt that a 6 year commitment can be rigidly enforced. If you don't want/need doctorates, of course, it isn't worth accepting. But if you do... Note that in the US, it would take about 6 years to do this also.

Comment: It would be of my best interest to accept the offer of 2+4 years with better financial support and at the same time be able to send out applications to PhD programs while getting my masters degree after 2 years. But this track program is quite new and there are no regulation documents and I don't know if it leaves a good impression to ask these to the faculty.